# Limit of the derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Under what conditions is true:

If
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\Phi(x,y)\rightarrow 0$$

then

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Phi(x,y)\rightarrow 0$$

Some time ago I studied this, however I do not remember this theorem, could someone tell me what the conditions. In advance, thank you very much.

Comment: @5xum My mistake I'll delete my comment. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for all $y$, the function $f:x\mapsto \Phi(x,y)$ has a horizontal asymptote of equation $z=0$ it work (in the plan $y=cste$). I hope I have helped you.